# limit of sum of Dirac delta functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

I'm reading *Approximation Theory and Approximation Practice: Extended Edition*, where in Chapter 12, potential theory:

> Another way to write $u(s)={1\over n+1}\sum_{j=0}^n\log|s-x_j|$ is as a Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral, $$u(s)=\int_{-1}^1\log|s-\tau|d\mu(\tau),$$ where $\mu$ is a measure consisting of a sum of Dirac delta functions: $$\mu(\tau)={1\over n+1}\sum_{j=0}^n\delta(\tau-x_j).$$

What I can't understand is that it claims as $n\to\infty$, equally spaced grids in $[-1,1]$ converge to the limiting measure $$\mu(\tau)=\frac12,$$ and Chebyshev grids in $[-1,1]$ converge to $$\mu(\tau)={1\over\pi\sqrt{1-\tau^2}}.$$ They seem to measure the density of grid points, but how can I work out the two limiting measures exactly?

Comment: If you think in terms of the Riemann integral, you can see that the weights attached to the delta functions must depend on the spacing... Even spacing gives what you wrote: weights all the same. With other spacing, the weights cannot all be the same, etc.